# Enforcing Specific language settings using Group Policy or .ADMX file?

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, microsoft-office-365, microsoft-office

People,

I need to enforce specific language settings for all of my users in the company for both Windows 10 and also Office 365 applications.

How can I enforce it using the group policy?

Do I need to install specific .ADMX template policy for the Office 2019 to allow me to achieve this standardization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Office, I think the [Office administrator templates](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49030) could be helpful.

First, please ensure the "specific language" of Office would be installed on users' PC.

Then to set Display language, `Configuration\Policies\Administrative Templates\Microsoft Office 2016\Language Preferences\Display Language`

For Editing Languages, go to `User Configuration\Policies\Administrative Templates\Microsoft Office 2016\Language Preferences\Editing Languages` to specify the language.

More information, please refer to [Use Group Policy to enforce language settings](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/deployoffice/office2016/customize-language-setup-and-settings-for-office-2016#use-group-policy-to-enforce-language-settings).

Comment: that's great, thank you @emily